# Images can be dragged and drop in textbox in jqgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textbox, drag-and-drop, jqgrid

In my rails application ,iam using jqgrid to enter data in rows.there is a description box which allows certain no of characters.The problem here is i can drag and drop images and urls which the description box accepts.How can i prevent it.
here is the short code i have taken out from the main after some edit..

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

     colNamesData = [ 'Description', 'Hours']
     colModelHash = [ 
     {name:'description',index:'description', width:130,sorttype:"text", editable:true, edittype:"textarea", editoptions: {rows:"5",cols:"25",maxlength:"255"}, stype:'text'},
     {name:'hours',index:'hours', width:130, align:'center',editable:true, edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"<%= hours_options %>"}, search:true, stype:'text'}
                      },
          ]
   $("#data_table").jqGrid({
      datatype: "local", 
      height: "auto",
      autowidth: true,
      ignoreCase: true,
      colNames: colNamesData, 
      colModel: colModelHash,
      pager: '#pager',
      rowNum:10,
      rowList:[10,25,50,100],
      sortname: 'hours',
      sortorder: 'desc',
      viewrecords: true,
      editurl:"/data_call.json", 
      caption: 'My info',

     },
      data:<%= raw @data_jqgrid_date.to_json %>
   });

   jQuery("#data_table").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,add:true,edit:false},{}, {}, {});  
   var details =  <%= raw @details.to_json %>
```

Comment: You should include the JavaScript code which are used on the client side. It is important **how** you implemented the features which you described in your question.

Comment: @oleg..Thanx..i have just put up a brief code for the idea of implementation..just check if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view you can have a JavaScript method.
Just bind the change method of that text box with the method.
Check the value, if it contains any invalid character then reset it to balnk('') and return false.

Comment: I suggest with client side check you can have some server site checks also. If there are some html chars then escape it before saving in the DB

Answer (score 1):

You can bind 'drop' event handler to the 'description' column having `edittype:"textarea"`. To do this you can include `dataEvents` which look like

```
editoptions: {
   dataEvents: [
       {
            type: 'drop',
            fn: function(e) {
                console.log('drop');
                if (e.originalEvent !== undefined &&
                    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer !== undefined &&
                    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData) {

                    console.log("URL: "+e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('URL'));
                    console.log("Text: "+e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
       }
   ]
}
```

in the code the URL and the Text dropped in the control will be displayed on the console and the dropping will be prevented. You can prevent the dropping depend on the data returned by `dataTransfer.getData('URL')` and `dataTransfer.getData('Text')`.